# Counting files over a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am counting files between certain numbers by the following:

```
for i in $(eval echo {$start..$stop}); do
ls /home/me/*/file_$i.txt 2> /dev/null | wc -l
done
```

`$(eval echo {$start..$stop})` is necessary as sequence expressions cannot take general input.

However, this does not do what I am looking for, as for each iteration of the loop, it counts if that individual file exists or not. Instead, I want it to iterate over all the files, but count the total number that exists between $start and $stop (keep in mind I am dealing with a large number of files and trying to avoid overflow). How could I modify my above scheme to count the total number of existing files, instead of checking whether each iterated file exists?

Comment: My previous question could not handle general values $start and $stop. Thus, the loop was necessary. @msp9011

Comment: I get the error "/usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long" if I place $(eval echo {$start..$stop}) directly in the file string, making the loop necessary.

Comment: Add the output of `wc -l` to a variable which you initialize with 0.

Comment: Are `$start` and `$stop` integers or letters?

Comment: You could simply move the `| wc -l` to after `done`, unless you also want to support filenames with embedded newlines (which your current code does not do).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Count=0
for i in {$start..$stop}; do
   Counter="$(ls /home/me/*/file_$i.txt 2> /dev/null | wc -l)"
   Count=$((Count+Counter))
done
echo "$Count"
```

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? As OP already pointed out in their question `{$start..$stop}` does not expand to (for instance) `7 8 9 10 11` but to literally `{7..11}`.

Comment: @Socowi, note that it's a limitation of `bash` only, The `{x..y}` operator comes from `zsh` and `{$start..$stop}` works fine there. It also works fine in `ksh93` or `yash`.

Comment: That's good to know, but doesn't make this answer correct. The question is tagged as [bash] and not as [zsh].

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop at all. Instead, list *all* files and use a command like `grep` or `akw` to filter out the files between `start` and `stop`. `printf` won't have the problem `Argument list too long` as it is a `bash` built-in.

```
printf '%s\0' /home/me/*/file_*.txt |
grep -cEzf <(seq "$start" "$stop" | sed 's/.*/_&\.txt$/')
```

<sub>Here we assume you have the GNU versions of `grep` which can handle null bytes. This is important to process paths safely. The null byte is the only character which cannot be part of a path so we can use it to separate paths.

If you don't have the GNU version you can create something that delimits paths by newlines under the assumption that no path contains a newline character. Replace `\0` with `\n` and remove the `-z` flag.</sub>

If you change `…_*.txt` to something else you may also have to update the `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `eval` unless you have no other alternative.  It is potentially dangerous, depending on the contents of the `$start` and `$stop` variables.  It is not a good idea to get into the habit of using it where it isn't necessary.
2. Don't use the output of `ls` for anything but viewing in a terminal.  Attempting to parse `ls`, even in the simplest fashion, can and will fail in all sorts of ways.   Use **anything** that can produce a NUL-separated list of filenames instead: `find -print0` is often a good choice.
3. The bash built-in `{x..y}` sequence expansion can't evaluate variables, but the standalone `seq` program can take variables as arguments.  It also has a useful `-s` option to specify the separator.

The following requires a version of `grep` that supports the `-z` option for NUL-separated input records (e.g. GNU, FreeBSD, and most other **modern** versions of `grep`).

```bsh
# build a regular expression matching the desired sequence
re="$(seq -s '|' "$start" "$stop")"

# use the RE with `find ... -print0` and `grep -E -z -c`
find /home/me/*/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file_*.txt' -print0 | 
  grep -Ezc "/file_($re)\.txt$"
```

For example, if `start=3` and `stop=7`, then `$re` will be `3|4|5|6|7`. The `grep` command would then expand to:

```
grep -Ezc "/file_(3|4|5|6|7)\.txt$"
```

---

BTW, the `-name 'file_*.txt'` arguments for the `find` command aren't required.  They can be dropped, and the pipeline will still run without error.  All they do is reduce the input data that needs to be processed by `grep`.  A very minor optimisation at best.

e.g.

```
find /home/me/*/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep -Ezc "/file_($re)\.txt$"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there's no need for a loop:

Suppose a range between 12 and 76:

```
ls -l | grep -e "file_1[2-9].txt" -e "file_[2-6][0-9].txt" -e "file_7[0-6].txt"
```

---

Files 12 to 19

```
"file_1[2-9].txt"
```

Files 20 to 69:

```
"file_[2-6][0-9].txt"
```

Files 70 to 76

```
"file_7[0-6].txt"
```

Comment: I guess this only works when `$start` and `$stop` are < 10. For numbers with multiple digits you have to generate a regex or use another tool like `awk`.

Comment: @Socowi Yes, this does not work for numbers >10. I need to use another method, as you mention.

Comment: Edited the answer, I'm not completely sure, but I think it does it. Feedback welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A `bash` solution:

```
(
shopt -s nullglob
start=1   # change as needed
stop=500  # change as needed
printf '%s\n' $(printf '/home/me/*/file_%s.txt\n' $(seq "$start" "$stop")) | wc -l
)
```

Enable `nullglob` to match only existing files and execute the script in a subshell `(…)`,
so we don't have to determine `nullglob`'s previous state and reset its old state when done. The inner `printf` is used to generate all possible filename patterns and the the outer `printf` is needed to 
interpret the `*` as glob character. The printed output lines are counted with `wc -l`.

Comment: Instead of `printf '%s\n' | wc -l` which would not work properly if file paths contained newline characters, you could do `printf '%.0sx' | wc -c`. Or define a `count() { echo "$#"; }` function that returns the number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use process substitution and grep -f to search only for files within a range.

E.g. To count all files named file_[0-9]+.txt between range of 10 to 20:

```
start=10
end=20
ls -f1 | grep -F -f <(printf "file_%s.txt\n" $(seq ${start} ${end}))|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
count=0 range="<$start-$stop>"
/home/me/*/file_$~range.txt(Ne['((!++count))'])
```

Would give you the count without storing the list of files in memory.

- `<1-100>` is a zsh glob operator that matches decimal numbers in that range (note that it matches on 2 but also 000002 for instance)
- `$~var` is like `$var` except that the content of `$var` is considered as a pattern as opposed to a literal value.
- `(Ne['code'])` is a glob qualifier
- `N`: enables `nullglob` for that pattern so it doesn't fail if the glob doesn't match any  file (which is always the case here).
- `e['code']` selects files based on the evaluation of the `code`. Here the code (`((!++count))`) increments `$count` and always returns false so the files are not selected (but `$count` has been incremented which is all we care about here).